# How Best To Implement ViewModel( in AndroidX) So Data Survives Configuration Changes

Tags: java, android, mvvm, androidx, android-viewmodel

I am trying to implement a ViewModel architecture for a RecyclerView in AndroidX, following the example as stated in [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) and [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#declaring_dependencies). Items in the recyclerView get selected on position clicked, but for some reason, the selected item de-select and revert to default after the device is rotated and configuration changed. I know there have been answers for questions like this in the past, but all I have seen are either not directly applicable in my case or are simply for deprecated cases.

CAN SOMEONE PLEASE TELL ME WHAT I AM DOING WRONG!

Below are snippets from my Code:

Dependencies added

```
dependencies {

def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"

// ViewModel
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"

// LiveData
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:$lifecycle_version"

// Saved state module for ViewModel
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:$lifecycle_version"

// Annotation processor
annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"

implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha02'
```

}

Repository Class:
public class TopicRepository {

```
private Application application;
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private ArrayList<RootTopic> topicGroupList;
private MutableLiveData<ArrayList<RootTopic>>topicGroupMLD;

public TopicRepository(Application application) {
    this.application = application;
    
}

public LiveData<ArrayList<RootTopic>> getRootTopicLD(String subject){
    if (topicGroupMLD == null){
        topicGroupMLD = new MutableLiveData<ArrayList<RootTopic>>();
        generateTopicGroup(subject);
    }
        return topicGroupMLD;
}

private void generateTopicGroup(final String subject){
    Log.d(TAG, "generateTopicGroup: CALLED");
    isRequestingMLD.postValue(true);
    final String subjectTopicGroupList = subject + "TopicGroupList";

    sharedPreferences = application.getSharedPreferences(AppConstant.Constants.PACKAGE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String serializedTopicGroup = sharedPreferences.getString(subjectTopicGroupList, null);
     if (serializedTopicGroup != null){

         Gson gson = new Gson();
         Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<RootTopic>>(){}.getType();
         topicGroupList = gson.fromJson(serializedTopicGroup, type);
         topicGroupMLD.postValue(topicGroupList);

     }else {//       - Not saved in SP

         Log.d(TAG, "getTopicGroup: NOT IN SP");
         new ActiveConnectionCheck(new ActiveConnectionCheck.Consumer() {
             @Override
             public void accept(Boolean internet) {
                 Log.d(TAG, "accept: CHECKED INTERNET");
                 if (internet){
                     Log.d(TAG, "accept: INTERNET CONNECTION = TRUE");
                     internetCheckMLD.postValue(AppConstant.Constants.IS_INTERNET_REQUEST_SUCCESS);

                     FirebaseFirestore fbFStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                     CollectionReference lectureRef = fbFStore.collection(subject);
                     lectureRef.orderBy(AppConstant.Constants.POSITION, Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
                             .get().addOnSuccessListener(
                             new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                 @Override
                                 public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {

                                     ArrayList<Topic>topicList = new ArrayList<>();
                                     ArrayList<String> rootTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

                                     for (QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots){
                                         Topic topic = snapshot.toObject(Topic.class);
                                         topicList.add(topic);
                                     }

                                     Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: TopicListSize = " + topicList.size());

                                     for (Topic topic : topicList){
                                         String rootTopicString = topic.getRootTopic();
                                         if (!rootTitleList.contains(rootTopicString)){
                                             rootTitleList.add(rootTopicString);
                                         }
                                     }

                                     Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: RootTitleListSize = " + rootTitleList.size());

                                    for (int x = 0; x < rootTitleList.size(); x ++){
                                        RootTopic rootTopic = new RootTopic(rootTitleList.get(x), new ArrayList<Topic>());
                                        topicGroupList = new ArrayList<>();
                                        topicGroupList.add(rootTopic);
                                    }

                                     for (int e = 0; e < topicList.size(); e++){
                                         addTopicToGroup(topicGroupList, topicList.get(e));
                                     }

                                     topicGroupMLD.postValue(topicGroupList);
                                     Gson gson = new Gson();
                                     String serializedTopicGroup = gson.toJson(topicGroupList);
                                     sharedPreferences.edit().putString(subjectTopicGroupList, serializedTopicGroup).apply();

                                     Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: TOPICGROUPSIZE = " + topicGroupList.size());
                                     Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: SERIALIZED GROUP = " + serializedTopicGroup);
                                     isRequestingMLD.postValue(false);

                                 }
                             }
                     ).addOnFailureListener(
                             new OnFailureListener() {
                                 @Override
                                 public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                     isRequestingMLD.postValue(false);
                                     Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: FAILED TO GET TOPICLIST e = " + e.toString());
                                 }
                             }
                     );

                 }else {
                     internetCheckMLD.postValue(AppConstant.Constants.IS_INTERNET_REQUEST_FAIL);
                     Log.d(TAG, "accept: InternetCONECTION = " + false);
                 }
             }
         });

     }

}

private void addTopicToGroup(ArrayList<RootTopic>rootGroup, Topic topic){
    for (int x = 0; x < rootGroup.size(); x++){
        RootTopic rootTopic = rootGroup.get(x);
        if (rootTopic.getRootTopicName().equals(topic.getRootTopic())){
            rootTopic.getTopicGroup().add(topic);
        }
    }
}
```

}

My ViewModel class

```
public class LectureViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

public static final String TAG = AppConstant.Constants.GEN_TAG + ":LectureVM";

private Application application;
private TopicRepository topicRepository;
private ArrayList<RootTopic> topicGroupList;


public LectureViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    this.application = application;
    topicRepository = new TopicRepository(application);
   
}


public LiveData<ArrayList<RootTopic>> getRootTopicListLD(String subject){

    return topicRepository.getRootTopicLD(subject);
}
```

}

Activity Implementing ViewModel

```
public class LectureRoomActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String TAG = AppConstant.Constants.GEN_TAG + " LecRoom";
private LectureViewModel lectureRoomVM;
private String subject;
private RecyclerView mainRecyclerView;

private RootTopicAdapter rootTopicAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lecture_room);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    subject = intent.getStringExtra(AppConstant.Constants.SUBJECT);

    mainRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    
    downloadVM = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(DownloadLectureViewModel.class);
    lectureRoomVM = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(LectureViewModel.class);
    lectureRoomVM.getRootTopicListLD(subject).observe(
            this,
            new Observer<ArrayList<RootTopic>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(ArrayList<RootTopic> rootTopics) {
            if (rootTopics != null){
                currentTopic = lectureRoomVM.getCursorTopic(subject, rootTopics);
                setUpRec(rootTopics, currentTopic);
            }
        }
    });

}


private void setUpRec( ArrayList<RootTopic>topicGroup, CursorTopic currentTopic){
     rootTopicAdapter = new RootTopicAdapter(topicGroup,
            new ArrayList<String>(), currentTopic.getParentPosition(),
            currentTopic.getCursorPosition());

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(
            this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false);

    mainRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mainRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    mainRecyclerView.setAdapter(rootTopicAdapter);

    Log.d(TAG, "setUpRec: SETTING REC");
}
```

}

Comment: Please state what data you want it to survive and it doesn't survive after configuration changes. What data you want to survive?

Comment: @Kozmotronik, A custom List of topics. The point is, the selected item in my Recyclerview reset to default position after a configuration change. What I hoped to achieve is that the selected position remains the same after the device is rotated.

Comment: For the states that related to a view for example last selected index of RecyclerView, use a variable in ViewModel class if you wanna survive it. There I'll show you a sample code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For saving and restoring UI related data you better use savedInstanceState Bundle to survive the last state. To achive this you simply override two methods in you UI activity. See the sample code snippet below.

In your RootTopicAdapter

```
// Add this where you detect the item click, probably in your adaptor class
private int lastRecyclerViewIndex; // define the variable to hold the last index
...

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    lastRecyclerViewIndex = getLayoutPosition();
}

public int getLastIndex() {
    return lastRecyclerViewIndex;
}
```

In your view model class

```
public class LectureViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    public static final String TAG = AppConstant.Constants.GEN_TAG + ":LectureVM";

    private Application application;
    private TopicRepository topicRepository;
    private ArrayList<RootTopic> topicGroupList;
    public boolean mustRestore; // Is there any data to restore
    public int lasIndexSelected;


    public LectureViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        this.application = application;
        topicRepository = new TopicRepository(application);
    
    }


    public LiveData<ArrayList<RootTopic>> getRootTopicListLD(String subject){

        return topicRepository.getRootTopicLD(subject);
    }
}
```

In you UI activity which uses the RecyclerView

```
public class LectureRoomActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
    private LectureViewModel lectureRoomVM;
    ...
    private RecyclerView mainRecyclerView;

    private RootTopicAdapter rootTopicAdapter;
    
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lecture_room);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        subject = intent.getStringExtra(AppConstant.Constants.SUBJECT);

        mainRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        
        downloadVM = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(DownloadLectureViewModel.class);
        lectureRoomVM = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(LectureViewModel.class);
        lectureRoomVM.getRootTopicListLD(subject).observe(
                this,
                new Observer<ArrayList<RootTopic>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ArrayList<RootTopic> rootTopics) {
                if (rootTopics != null){
                    currentTopic = lectureRoomVM.getCursorTopic(subject, rootTopics);
                    setUpRec(rootTopics, currentTopic);
                    // Exactly here, after setting up the data get your index for example
                    if(lectureRoomVM.mustRestore){
                        // Check the item count in the adaptor to avoid crashes
                        if(mainRecyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount >= lastRecyclerViewIndex){
                            mainRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(lastRecyclerViewIndex).itemView.performClick();
                        }
                        // After the restoration set the mustRestore to false
                        lectureRoomVM.mustRestore = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(E, "onDestroy");
        /* 
         * Here just set the mustRestore to true in order to be able to restore in onCreate method.
         * If the application itself is not destroyed your data will still be live in the
         * memory thanks to the ViewModel's life cycle awarness.
         */
        lectureRoomVM.mustRestore = true;
    }
}
```

There you go. Try this logic carefully without bugs. Then I think you will achive what you want to get.

Comment: big thanks for the effort, but the real issue for me is getting the ViewModel to work as it should. Truth is, I basically want to bypass the whole idea of the SaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState callbacks, not just for the sake of this recyclerview, but also for other parts of the project.

Comment: I see, then what you have to do is easier than my code. Just create a variable in the viewmodel instance say lastIndex, then do what I did in the InstanceState override methods. You don't even have to save it because ViewModel object is not destroyed until the whole app is destroyed. In onCreate method read the lastIndex value after setting up the recyclerview as I did in the onRestoreInstanceState method and you will get what you left before the activity had destroyed. Then you can use the same logic for other data you want to survive. Is it clear or want me to write a basic snippet for it?

Comment: Alright, let me try it out. I'l revert shortly

Comment: Still not Working, The ViewModel is failing me. Tried creating an int variable in the VieModel class which I get to to update  it value on item click using a call in my Activity. Then, I did a Livedata callback to get the current value of the position. Thats where I get to pass the data to my Adapter. It works fine until I rotate the device. Immediately the configuration change, the LiveData reset it self to default and not retain it last value. I think something is wrong with the depencies or the ViewModel setup

Comment: Please help check out the dependencies I added and my ViewModel initialization if I am getting it wrong. The ViewModel concept looks basic, but I just don understand why the LiveData Callback keep resetting on configuration change

Comment: Have you tried my last updated code? It didn't work either? If didn't, Update your question with your latest code for futher help. The data in a ViewModel class must not reset until you exit from your application. There must be something missing.

Comment: it finally worked with a tiny tweak to the solution you provided. I just had to remove the last line where you set the must restore to false after restoring state. I'm accepting your solution. ONE QUESTION THOUGH, How will this work if it were to be an Exoplayer I am returning with the LiveData Observer? Because it wouldn't be a nice user experience for the player to buffer to the last save position after every configuration change.

Comment: Glad for you. If I get your question right, your question was the behind reason I used the mustrestore flag. Since LiveData can change update any time in the application, we don't want to restore the index position every time the LiveData updates the data. Must be only once for each configuration change. That's why I set the mustRestore in onDestroy in order to know if restoration required in onCreate method, after detecting the required restoration I clear the mustRestore so that it doesn't set the position in every update callback redundantly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226424/discussion-between-kozmotronik-and-eric).